Efficient Ownership Validation in Django Rest Framework and Postgres for Inventory Management API
I'm developing an inventory management API using Django Rest Framework and PostgreSQL, where users can create, update, and interact with items in their inventory. One challenge I'm facing is efficiently validating ownership before allowing users to perform operations that involve multiple related items.
Database Structure:
Users

id: Integer
...

Items

id: Integer
user_id: ForeignKey(User)
...

Components

id: Integer
parent_item_id: ForeignKey(Item)
child_item_id: ForeignKey(Item)
child_qty: Integer
...

Orders

id: Integer
user_id: ForeignKey(User)
...

Order_items

id: Integer
order_id: ForeignKey(Order)
item_id: ForeignKey(Item)
item_qty: Integer
...

Scenario:
Consider a scenario where a user wants to create a new item (e.g., a "flower basket") composed of multiple components. Before allowing this creation, I need to ensure that the user owns all the required components.
Current Approach:
My current approach involves:

Fetching all necessary components.
Validating ownership of these components against the requesting user.
Proceeding with item creation if ownership checks pass.
Returning an error response if any ownership check fails.

Optimization Concerns:
I'm concerned about:

The potential inefficiency of multiple database queries (one per component).
Overhead due to looping through and checking each component.

Proposed Solutions & Questions:

Batch Ownership Check: Is there a way to optimize ownership validation by batching database queries or using a single query to check ownership of multiple components at once?

Permission Handling: Would DRF's permission classes (e.g., IsOwnerOrReadOnly) or custom permission checks be suitable for this scenario?

Transaction Management: Should operations involving multiple database writes (like creating an item with its components) be wrapped in a transaction to ensure atomicity?


Conclusion:
While my current approach works, I'd like to optimize my API's performance as much as possible. Any insights or alternative strategies would be greatly appreciated, even if it's just to tell me that I'm being overly concerned with premature optimization

What's up with the Item/Component structure? With the forein keys, it may look like Item1 <-parent- Component1 -child-> Item2 <-parent- Component2 -child-> Item3 ... Couldn't you do a simple hierarchy?

There's no way to answer this question in a general way. Everything in software is a tradeoff and depends on your specific, probably non-functional, requirements.
